# Enabling PulseAudio Equalizer by default for all programs

Tags: pulseaudio, equalizer

I have PulseAudio Equalizer and it's working great, but it goes back to default every time I start a new program or browser, so I have to activate it again in PulseAudio Volume Control.

To try to fix it, I typed the following commands into `default.pa`, but it didn't help:

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect ; load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the eq sliders to the preferences that suit you or select a preset. Select the Apply button. Put a checkmark in Enable EQ and Keep Settings. This should keep the eq alive and active for browsers and players.

Firefox gave me some trouble with Pulse eq at first but I adjusted the settings in Sound and no issues after that. Hope this helps

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Via pavucontrol gui, in tab output-devices, associated with output device "FFT Based Equalizer", I found a button whose tool tip says "set as fallback" which caused it (the eq) to be used for new sources.